# Selenium - How much am I hitting the server?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using selenium to scrape information from a website.

The page is behind a login so I can't provide an example - but basically I need to gather data on approx. 800 fields on the one page.

Currently it boils down to me navigating to the correct page and then running

`for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id]'):
                some_list.append(i.get_attribute('textContent'))`

My question is;

- **Does using `get_attribute` place any impact on the responding server?**

Or is the full page 'cached' and then I am simply reading the values that are already loaded?

Just want to make sure I'm being kind to the other party and not doing 800 calls for get_attribute!

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get_attribute` is retrieving data from sources already downloaded. You are not making requests to a web server when you execute that command